# Does Weblogic 9.x support the 2.4 Servlet standard?

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

Seems like a simple enough question but I can't seem to find the answer. And hey, dead simple questions like this with dead simple answers is what Joel and Jeff want SO to be all about, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://e-docs.bea.com/wls/docs92/compatibility/compatibility.html

> BEA WebLogic Server is one hundred percent J2EE 1.4 compatible

...which means that it supports the [servlet 2.4 specification](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/reference/api/index.html).